# BeautifulSoup SoupStrainer strain html and pdf links

Tags: python, scripting, beautifulsoup

What do I need to pass as a regex pattern to grab both html and pdfs from an HTML webpage? So far, what I have is below. I assumed that I needed to use an OR statement, but that didn't really work as expected.

```
status, response = http.request("http://www.example.com")
htmlandpdfonly=SoupStrainer('a', href=re.compile('html|pdf'))
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese = htmlandpdfonly):
    if(link.has_key('href')):
        print link['href']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# find ".html" or ".pdf" in a string
match = re.compile('\.(html|pdf)')

# parse page content
status, response = http.request("http://www.example.com")
page = BeautifulSoup(response)

# check links
for link in page.findAll('a'):
    try:
        href = link['href']
        if re.search(match, href):
            print href
    except KeyError:
        pass
```